# Probability of success in $n$ trials

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

I'm stuck on my statistics homework and would appreciate your help.

**Question**: Repeated independent trials of a certain experiment are carried out. On each trial the probability of success is $0.12$. Find the smallest value of $n$ such that the probability of at least one success in $n$ trials is more than $0.95$.

**My attempt**:

$X \sim B(n,0.12)$

$P(X \ge 1) = 1-P(X \le 1)$

$P(X \le 1) = 0.88^n + 0.12n(0.88)^{n-1}$

$0.88^n + 0.12n(0.88)^{n-1} \gt 0.05$

After a page of algebra I reached an equation that I couldn't solve (of the form $e^x +bx + c = 0$) so I knew I must be doing something wrong. Is this the correct way to approach the problem? How else can I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oops, you made a mistake.  $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)$.  You have it as $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$

Comment: @GregoryGrant As it turns out, I am extremely stupid. Thank you

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes sometimes, you're only stupid if you make mistakes every time.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: Why did you downvote? What makes this question bad? I'd like to improve my asking technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, you made a mistake.  $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)$.  You have it as $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $P(X \geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-0.88^n\geq 0.95$

Comment: Any comment for the downvote ? Some votes are really weird.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and don't understand the downvote either. It's a valid answer and it works. People seem to be much more vindictive on this  site than on other SE sites

Comment: @imulsion Thanks for the vote and your reaction. I don´t have experience with other SE sites. The following rule would be helpful: If someone is voting down, then he/she has to post a comment. This would greatly reduce the number of senseless downvoting.

Comment: Shall we make a post on meta about this issue?

Comment: @imulsion This is a good idea. I have to think about it how to phrase the post. I give a report, if I have an idea. At the moment a have several things to do. Thus It would take a few hours. If you have made a post or have a idea for the text, then it would be nice to leave a comment here.

Comment: I haven't made a post but I do think we need to highlight the somewhat hostile attitude on this site. I'm involved with several SE sites (notably Arqade and SO (check my profile)) and this one definitely feels a lot less welcoming. My ideas: Note in the post how people can downvote for no reason. Use this question as well as others (if you've experienced it before) for sources otherwise no one will believe us. Also look at @Sloan 's answer below. It was downvoted and IMO nothing is wrong with it either. I think the general gist should be that we aren't happy with the situation.

Comment: In terms of solving the problem, there isn't really an easy solution. I like your idea of being forced to leave a comment in order to downvote. Maybe there could be a "why are you downvoting" message box that appears or something, but we can leave that discussion for the post.

Comment: @imulsion Any improvement is welcome (content and language) $$ * $$ imulsion and I have seen many times before that responses have been voted down even though they were right - usually without leaving a comment. It is therefore impossible to ask the voter why he has so voted . We would suggest that someone, who has downvoted an answer he must leave a comment at the same time. This would have two advantages :

1. You can make an inquiry .

2. It would not be so lightly and inaccurate voted down, because everybody can see, which user who have voted down .

What do you think of our proposal ?

Comment: Tone and content looks good but I have some grammatical corrections and a couple of extra additions (I assume English isn't your first language):

imulsion and I have seen many times before that responses have been voted down by multiple individuals even though they were mathematically correct - usually without leaving a comment. [insert sources etc here] It is therefore impossible to ask the voter why he has decided that the question is not fit for the site's format - as they cannot be identified from votes alone.On other SE sites this isn't really a problem - it is usually fairly [cont]

Comment: obvious whether a post is good quality or not. On this site however questions and answers can be somewhat subjective in quality, usually because there are multiple different methods to solving a problem. Therefore, we would suggest that someone who has downvoted an answer must leave a comment at the same time. This would have three advantages : 1. You can make an inquiry as to your downvote. 2. It would not be so lightly and inaccurately voted down, because everybody can see which users have voted down. [cont]

Comment: 3. It would make it easier to learn what you are doing wrong and how to improve your asking/answering technique, which would improve the overall quality of posts on the site. What do you think of our proposal?

Answer (score 0):

$P($at least one success$) + P($no success$)=1 \implies P($at least one success$)=1-(0.88)^n$. I think you can proceed from here.